# React router always showing NotFound component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, router, react-router-dom

I have routes objects from backend and set it to routes like this and when I am set NotFound component, which route is '*' to default in switch/case or to case "NotFound" which commented now, it all the time show with all components after them.

I mean it works all the time, not just in the wrong URL way

```
function getProperComponentData(el) {
  switch (el.label) {
    case "Home":
      return { ...el, exact: true, Component: Home };
    case "Categories":
      return { ...el, Component: Categories };
    case "Popular":
      return { ...el, Component: Popular };
    case "Movies-by-Categorie":
      return { ...el, Component: MoviesByCategory };
    case "Asset":
      return { ...el, Component: AssetDetails };
    case "Discover":
      return { ...el, Component: Discover };
    // case "NotFound":
    //   return { ...el, Component: NotFound };
    default:
      return { ...el, Component: NotFound };
  }
}

const RoutesApp = ({ routes }) => {
  if (routes) {
    const array = routes.map((el) => {
      const { id, exact, route, Component } = getProperComponentData(el);
      return (
        <Route key={id} exact={exact} path={route} component={Component} />
      );
    });

    return array;
  }

  return null;
};
```

I've already tried a lot..
Even delete not-found route from backend object,
and set it manually to Router like this

```
        <Router>
            <NavBar menu={this.state.menu ? this.state.menu : false} />

            <Switch>
              <RoutesApp
                routes={this.state.routes ? this.state.routes : false}
              />
              <Route path="*" component={NotFound} /> // here I set it manually but delete from routes at line above (this way it's not working at all)
            </Switch>
          </Router>
```

But in this way at totally not work

Any ideas?
[it shows all the time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKmrB.jpg)

Comment: When composing a title try and explain the problem, not that you have a problem or need help. It's presumed that you do since you're asking a question on Stack Overflow. People use the title to quickly scan for questions they can answer. The more you confuse that, the less help you'll end up getting. I've tried to reframe this question in the title, so can you confirm that's a better interpretation? Your question is far from clear as to the root problem at hand.

Comment: What is the contents of `this.state.routes`? That seems to be the source of your problem and it's not shown.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll be more straight how to ask.

Comment: In this.state.routes I have an array of objects: 
[
0: {id: "menu-home", label: "Home", route: "/"}
1: {id: "menu-categories", label: "Categories", route: "/categories"}
2: {id: "menu-popular", label: "Popular", route: "/popular"}
3: {id: "movies-by-categorie", label: "Movies-by-Categorie", route: "/movies/:category_id"}
4: {id: "asset", label: "Asset", route: "/asset/:id"}
5: {id: "discover", label: "Discover", route: "/discover"}
6: {id: "not-found", label: "NotFound", route: "*"}
]

Comment: That would work better if you edited your question and amended it with that information and apply proper code formatting.

Comment: Is the issue that NotFound is always showing, or never showing?

Comment: yes, it's always showing with other components

Comment: All components works great, and NotFound Component always show at each page after proper component

Comment: You have two routes to the NotFound component, one auto-generated, one with a manual `Route`. Is that correct?

Comment: NotFound should be set otherwise, ask the guys from backend for more insights

Comment: No, its just for testing. When I have manual Route - it's not working at all

Comment: When I have auto-generated it show's all the time

Comment: There is a picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKmrB.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That occurs because all children of a `<Switch>` should be `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` elements.
You can check more about it in react-router-dom [docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch/children-node).

So, one solution for your code would be do something like that:

```js
 // I've just removed `RoutesApp` and rendered .map directly
 <Switch>
   {this.state.routes && this.state.routes.map((el) => {
     const { id, exact, route, Component } = getProperComponentData(el);
     return (
       <Route
         key={id}
         exact={exact}
         path={route}
         component={Component}
       />
     );
   })}
   <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
 </Switch>
```